# Android: how to show icon in ActionBar but not in the Options Menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I show an icon in an ActionBar but not in the Options Menu at the same time? Is it possible via XML only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you have the action bar available, you don't have an action menu anymore. The menu items are not doubled.

If you get the action bar on Android SDK > 10 and the options menu on Android SDK <= 10, then consider using ActionBarSherlock, to make the action bar backwards compatible for older Android versions too:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Action items are included in the overflow menu, which behaves as a regular menu on devices with a hardware menu button (Galaxy S3). Even if you specify android:showAsAction="always". You don't always want this.

Comment: The regular menu still appears on new devices that support the action bar (like the S3) **if** the Application was compiled with a target of SDK 10 or less.

Comment: This is incorrect. My target is SDK 15, and the Galaxy S3 is 'displaying' only a hardware menu button without the overflow in the action bar, while the Galaxy Nexus is displaying a hardware menu button together with an overflow button in the action bar.

Comment: Aparently Samsumg though that for their ICS version a menu button is more suitable, since their devices comes with a menu button anyway which I found it disturbing considering is such a popular phone and we are unable to set an overflow natively……